# Вычислить в процентах положение курсора по ширине внутри блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

```css
.player {
padding: 50px;  
cursor: pointer;
}
.player .range {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
.player .range .option {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <div class="range">
    <div class="option">50%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как вычислить в процентах положение курсора по ширине внутри блока?

Хочу сделать ползунок для плеера.

Интересует именно код - засорять сайт огромной тучей плагинов не охота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень просто, нужно ширину трека разделить на 100 и умножить на проценты `width / 100 * percent`.

Для примера если ширина трека `200px` и нужно установить в позицию `30%`, то расчеты будут такими -

```
200 / 100 * 30 = 60; 60px это позиция 30%
```

И наоборот, если известно что курсор находится в `60px` то проценты -

```
60 / 200 * 100 = 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вешаете на элемент обработчик события `mousemove`, в объекте события можно получить доступ к св-вам `offsetX, offsetY`

```
el.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var width = e.target.offsetWidth;
    var mouseX = e.offsetX; 
    var percent = (x * 100) / width; 
    // процент смешения курсора от левого края элемента
}
```

Comment: А как поймать не простой клик, а именно удержание - что-бы при движении курсора снова срабатывала функция?

Comment: @W_0rld, `mousemove` именно движение мышки, а не клик

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".mouseEventOption").mousedown(function(e) {
  clicked = true;
});
$(".mouseEventOption").mouseup(function(e) {
  clicked = false;
});
$(".mouseEventOption").mousemove(function(e) {
  if (clicked == true) {
    offset = $(this).offset();
    cursor = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    width = $(this).outerWidth();
    percent = cursor / width * 100;
    if (percent > 100) {
      percent = 100;
    }
    param = ~~percent / 100;
    $(".option").css("width", ~~percent + "%");
    $(".option").html(~~percent);
  }
});
```

```css
.player {
  padding: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.player .range {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
.player .range .option {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://w-0rld.ru/files/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="player">
  <div class="range">
    <div class="mouseEventOption">
      <div class="option">50%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мой готовый вариант!